# jpa Inheritance for relational entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

i'm using a library which have some entity and relations 
like this :

```
public class BaseEntity1{

    private Long id;

    private List<BaseEntity2> baseEntity2List;
}

public class BaseEntity2{
    private Long id;

    private String title;
}
```

Entities have no jpa annotation's

i need to persist them into database 
so i extend them and Override getter's to add jpa annotations
like this :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ChildEntity1 extends BaseEntity1{

    @Override
    @Id
    public Long getId(){
        ..
    }

    @Override
    @OneToMany
    public List<BaseEntity2> getBaseEntity2List(){
            ..
        }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ChildEntity2 extends BaseEntity2{

    @Override
    @Id
    public Long getId(){
        ..
    }

    @Override
    @Column
    public String getName(){
        ..
    }
}
```

my problem is that OneToMany relation , i have no idea to replace BaseEntity2 to ChildEntity2
Does anyone have any idea ?